# The dirtree mode not present installed using melpa

Tags: require, load

My Emacs version is 25.2.2.

I installed dirtree using melpa. But `M-x dirtree` is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Command `dirtree` is [not marked](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/dirtree/blob/ba55f1e716e386fdd37cb8e7f48616e405dc7251/dirtree.el#L98) for [autoloading](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) so you need do `(require 'dirtree)` first.

Or follow instructions provided in `dirtree` [commentary section](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/dirtree/blob/ba55f1e716e386fdd37cb8e7f48616e405dc7251/dirtree.el#L38):

> Put the following into your ~/.emacs:
>
> `(autoload 'dirtree "dirtree" "Add directory to tree view" t)`